# Need to display the Max and Min Grade from a list of numbers

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, max, min

I need to input a list of grades and have the code stop when I input a character. It would then display the maximum grade and the minimum grade.

I created a `while loop`, but when I run the code, it keeps looping and won't stop.

```
public class MaxMinGrades{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    double maxGrade = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double minGrade = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter as many student grades as you like. Enter a character to stop.");
    double grades = input.nextDouble();

    while(input.hasNextDouble()) {
      if (grades > maxGrade) {
        maxGrade = grades;
      }
      if (grades < minGrade) {
        minGrade = grades;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("The highest grade is: " + maxGrade);
    System.out.println("The lowest grade is: " + minGrade);
  }
}
```

I would input: `50` `66.85` `73.5` `78.9` `77` q.

The output would be: The highest grade is: `78.9`
The lowest grade is: `50.0`

Comment: `input.hasNextDouble()` will return `true` but nothing is being read inside the loop, so it will return `true` on next iteration and again and again... as long as the double is not being consumed (and `grades` is always `50` since only being read once [outside the loop])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MaxMinGrades{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    double maxGrade = 0.0;
            double minGrade = 100.0;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter as many student grades as you like. Enter a character to stop.");


            while(input.hasNextDouble()) {
            double grades = input.nextDouble();
              if (grades > maxGrade) {
                maxGrade = grades;
              }
              if (minGrade > grades) {
                minGrade = grades;
              }
            }
            System.out.println("The highest grade is: " + maxGrade);
            System.out.println("The lowest grade is: " + minGrade);
  }
}
```

With this there is break condition inside of the `while loop`. When something changes the `boolean` condition is checked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no break condition in the while loop.
The scanner will continue listening for input.
The loop will only exit if a non-double character is entered.

You are also not actually getting the next input on each iteration. You need to call `input.nextDouble()` inside the loop.

If you want it to exit on its own, you need to add a breaking condition.
For example, you could stop after a certain number of inputs like:

```
int gradeCount = 0;
while(input.hasNextDouble() && gradeCount < 6) {
  grades = input.nextDouble();
  gradeCount += 1;

  // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points

1 . As soon as you get first entry you need to assign Min and Max with that value.

2 . variable grades should be updated with latest input inside the loop.

```
public class MaxMinGrades {
public static void main(String[] args){
    double maxGrade = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double minGrade = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter as many student grades as you like. Enter a character to stop.");
    double grades = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("first entry="+grades);
    minGrade = maxGrade = grades;

    while(input.hasNextDouble()) {
        grades = input.nextDouble();
        if (grades > maxGrade) {
            maxGrade = grades;
        }
        if (grades < minGrade) {
            minGrade = grades;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The highest grade is: " + maxGrade);
    System.out.println("The lowest grade is: " + minGrade);
}
```

}